# create the project after getting an error while run already created project

Tags: android, react-native

create the project after getting an error while run already created  project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `npm start -- --reset-cache` in the terminal and then open up a new one and run the project on your emulator again.

Comment: try many time but not working .above npstart -- --reset-cache

Answer (score 0):

try below command or try with **sudo** word

```
react-native start
```